# Why is my array returning duplicate information?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm somewhat new to PHP's PDO and getting my head around why it's doing something a bit strange. I have the following code (works as intended).

```
$db = new Database;

$query = $db->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :value LIMIT 1' );

$query->bindParam( ':value', $value );

$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetch();
```

However, I'm curious as to why it's returning a seemingly duplicated response. This is an example of what it returns:

```
/file.php:X:
array (size=X)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  'fullname' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  'email' => string 'bob@example.com' (length=15)
  2 => string 'bob@example.com' (length=15)
...
```

I have columns in my database for `ID`, `fullname` and `email` etc etc, **but why is it also returning key value pairs twice where the second one defaults to an int based key?**

Comment: Look at `fetch_style` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php or `mode` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php

Comment: `$query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.  Basically its returning both an associative array and an indexed array  AKA `FETCH_BOTH`.  For me I always set `$PDO->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` then the default is just the associative array.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the desired fetching style, and by default it's set to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` and that's why you get duplicate data. So You need to specify the desired style of the returned array(either indexed by number or by string, aka associative array, or object...), you need to change this line:

```
$result = $query->fetch();
```

into this to fetch an associative array:

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or this to fetch a classic array indexed by numbers beginning from 0:

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

There are more fetching styles, you can see the php manual for more informations [pdo fetch method](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Hope I pushed you further.